# Makefile with source get error `No such file or directory`

Tags: macos, makefile

I have a really simple `Makefile` that's doing `source` to set ENV variables. But it doesn't work if I call it from `Makefile`

I get this error

```
make dev
source ./bin/authenticate.sh
make: source: No such file or directory
make: *** [dev] Error 1
```

The script exists.

If I run this in command-line it works.

```
source ./bin/authenticate.sh
Works!
```

This is my `Makefile`

```
test:
    pytest -s

dev:
    source ./bin/authenticate.sh
```

I'm using OSX. I'm not sure if this would make a difference.

Comment: At a guess, your Make is using a shell which does not support the builtin `source`. You can use `$(info $(SHELL))` to find out what Make is using, `echo $SHELL` to find out what your command line is, and `SHELL := ...` at the top of your makefile to set one to the other.

Comment: Does the makefile work if you use `. ./bin/authenticate.sh`? The dot (`.`) is the POSIX way to source a file.

Answer (score 23):

tldr; lose the `source`, use the dot (`.`) like this:

```
test:
        pytest -s

dev:
        . ./bin/authenticate.sh
```

Longer explanation follows...

It doesn't work because `make` is looking for a `source` *program* in the `$PATH`. This fails because `source` is a (non-POSIX) shell builtin, not an executable program on any conventional UNIX-like system.

I was able to replicate failure shown in the question; the following (much abridged) output was generated on Ubuntu 16.04 with GNU Make v4.1:

```
$ strace -f -s65536 -- make dev 2>&1 | grep 'authenticate'
read(3, "test:\n\tpytest -s\n\ndev:\n\tsource ./bin/authenticate.sh\n", 4096) = 53
write(1, "source ./bin/authenticate.sh\n", 29source ./bin/authenticate.sh
[pid 32100] execve("/usr/local/sbin/source", ["source", "./bin/authenticate.sh"], [/* 82 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 32100] execve("/usr/local/bin/source", ["source", "./bin/authenticate.sh"], [/* 82 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 32100] execve("/usr/sbin/source", ["source", "./bin/authenticate.sh"], [/* 82 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 32100] execve("/usr/bin/source", ["source", "./bin/authenticate.sh"], [/* 82 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 32100] execve("/sbin/source", ["source", "./bin/authenticate.sh"], [/* 82 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 32100] execve("/bin/source", ["source", "./bin/authenticate.sh"], [/* 82 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

You can see that `make` made six failed attempts to find the `source` program; i.e., one for each component of my `$PATH`.

If `source` is changed to `.`, `make` changes its strategy; instead of trying to find and execute a program, it just passes the rule body to the system shell:

```
$ strace -f -s65536 -- make dev 2>&1 | grep 'authenticate'
read(3, "test:\n\tpytest -s\n\ndev:\n\t. ./bin/authenticate.sh\n", 4096) = 48
write(1, ". ./bin/authenticate.sh\n", 24. ./bin/authenticate.sh
[pid 32122] execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", ". ./bin/authenticate.sh"], [/* 82 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32122] open("./bin/authenticate.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

The kind of shell used by `make` determines which shell builtins get expanded within each `Makefile` rule. You can tell `make` to use a shell of your choosing like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
SHELL = /bin/bash
test:
        pytest -s

dev:
        source ./bin/authenticate.sh
```

Since `bash` defines the builtin `source` as a synonym for `.`, the rule using `source` now succeeds:

```
$ strace -f -s65536 -- make dev 2>&1 | grep 'authenticate'
read(3, "SHELL = /bin/bash\ntest:\n\tpytest -s\n\ndev:\n\tsource ./bin/authenticate.sh\n", 4096) = 71
write(1, "source ./bin/authenticate.sh\n", 29source ./bin/authenticate.sh
[pid 32573] execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source ./bin/authenticate.sh"], [/* 82 vars */]) = 0
[pid 32573] open("./bin/authenticate.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

References:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins
- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell

Comment: how do you then deactivate from the virtual env as that also doesn't work in make

Comment: @Wayneio, if you're having a problem within a virtualenv or similar development environment, then I encourage you to ask a new question specific to your chosen tool.

Comment: @Wayneio if you are using conda, you should be able to use `conda deactivate`, you can also just let the `make` recipe end since the updated environment inside the recipe will not propagate back to the environment in your current interactive shell session.

Comment: can you add an example make file that uses `.` its still not working for me on osx

Comment: @HarryMoreno done and done.

Answer (score 1):

do `cd bin && source authenticate.sh` it works